# Share source code via GitHub or other in general: How to remove the sign-on info from settings or general in Xcode iOS app -

Tags: ios, xcode, set, profile, account

Client of mine want to send the iOS Xcode files (not backend) - under development - all certs for apple are generated including 3rd notif related certs, etc. as needed.

Would like to remove developer info from Xcode i.e. client’s info this case.  is it in .pbxproj for project files? or am i missing any insight in this to successfully accomplish this?

Comment: Whould this question be more on-toppic on superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this has to do more with Xcode set up and app bundle identifier.  Recommend the following:

[x] Empty out details in Bundle Identifier (General tab > Bundle Identifier)

[x] Notification related files from the end user will be associated to the end product with setting ready for them.

Comment: Cool!  i had discovered this thru client needs and got it done.